# Understanding OFF value in glibc logf function

Tags: c, floating-point, glibc, logarithm

I am trying to understand the mechanics of the logarithm implementation in the GNU C Library that can be found under glibc > sysdeps > ieee754 > flt-32 > e_logf.c

https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/ieee754/flt-32/e_logf.c

Especially the OFF value (0x3f330000) bugs me in two ways.

1. How is it used to get the exponent k? I know the floating-point as integer interpretation and then shifting bits and subtracting the bias way, e.g. for a (positive) float x = 2^k * z

`int k = (asuint(x) >> 23) - 127;`

Here it seems to work the other way round, but I don't understand how that'd work.

2. Moreover, there's this comment:

`/* x = 2^k z; where z is in range [OFF,2*OFF] and exact. [...] */`

And I don't understand why z (the mantissa as I understand it) would lie in that interval and not [1, 2).

There's more I don't get but maybe I can figure it out once I understand what OFF stands for. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Taking the second question first,

> 2. Moreover, there's this comment:
>
> ```
> /* x = 2^k z; where z is in range [OFF,2*OFF] and exact. [...] */
> ```
>
> And I don't understand why z (the mantissa as I understand it) would
> lie in that interval and not [1, 2).

With respect to that formula, interpreting the place values of the bits of `z`'s binary representation such that `z` always falls in any particular non-empty interval is just a question how you choose `k`.  Thus, that `z` lies in the particular interval specified in the comment can be taken as a definition.  Without such a definition, there are infinitely many pairs of `z` and `k` that satisfy the formula.

> 1. How is [`OFF`] used to get the exponent k? I know the floating-point as integer interpretation and then shifting bits and subtracting the bias way, e.g. for a (positive) float x = 2^k * z
>
>    int k = (asuint(x) >> 23) - 127;
>
> Here it seems to work the other way round, but I don't understand how
> that'd work.

You can shift then subtract or subtract a different, shifted value then shift.  You can convert back and forth between the two forms algebraically.  It's just distributing a multiplicative operation over an additive one vs. factoring it out.

The value defined for `OFF` is equal to `((126 << 23) + 0x330000)`, which is strictly between `126 << 23` and `127 << 23`.  The code you linked does this:

> ```
> tmp = ix - OFF;
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> k = (int32_t) tmp >> 23; /* arithmetic shift */
> ```

Given the defined value of `OFF`, that's the same as ...

```
k = (ix - (126 << 23) - 0x330000) >> 23;
```

.  The value 0x330000 has only 22 significant bits, so the result of that computation will be either equal to `(ix >> 23) - 126` (in most cases; does that look familiar?) or one less than that.  It's computing the exponent based on a bias of 126.

Why 126 instead of 127?  I think it's because the computation does not include the the implicit leading 1 bit in the mantissa.

The question remains what the role of the extra 0x330000 is.  I'm not positive, but I am inclined to guess that it is some sort of tweak parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The code referenced in the question is very likely based on the assumption that the C type `float` is mapped to the `binary32` type of the IEEE-754 floating-point standard. John Bollinger's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66146867/780717) already addresses the bit-level manipulation of `binary32` numbers used during argument reduction.

Without having looked at the code, just based on the code comments in the question it is clear that `OFF` represents the lower bound of the interval over which the core approximation employed by the code is valid. Specifically, the bit pattern specified by `0x3f330000` interpreted as a `binary32` number corresponds to  the value `0x1.660000p-1` which is approximately 0.69921875. The upper bound is twice the lower bound, or about 1.3984375, as the cited code comment points out.

Typical implementations of `log` ultimately approximate `log1p` around zero, which means they approximate `log` around unity. It is numerically advantageous for the lower bound of the core approximation to be `>= exp(-0.5)` ~= 0.60653 and the upper bound to be `<= exp (0.5)` ~= 1.64872, under the restriction that the upper bound is twice the lower bound. Within those constraints the particular choice of cutoff is a *design parameter* of the `log` algorithm. It is impossible to know why the code's author made this particular choice. A reasonable guess is that this choice minimizes the overall numerical error of the implementation.

Below I am showing a simple ISO-C99 implementation of `logf()` where I experimented with three different design choices for the cutoff value for precisely this reason, ultimately settling on the cutoff value of 2/3 for providing the smallest [ulp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) error. This code also contains a portable implementation of the argument reduction using standard C library functions that I would hope make it easier to understand the bit-level manipulations.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>

int32_t float_as_int (float a) { int32_t r; memcpy (&r, &a, sizeof r); return r; }
float int_as_float (int32_t a) { float r; memcpy (&r, &a, sizeof r); return r; }

/* natural logarithm */
float my_logf (float a)
{
    float m, r, s, t, i, f;
    int32_t e;
#if LOG_VARIANT == 1
    // max ulp err = 0.86280
    const float cutoff_f = 0.707106781f;
    const int32_t cutoff_i = 0x3f3504f3;
#elif LOG_VARIANT == 2
    // max ulp err = 0.88098
    const float cutoff_f = 0.750000000f;
    const int32_t cutoff_i = 0x3f400000;
#elif LOG_VARIANT == 3
    // max ulp err = 0.85089
    const float cutoff_f = 0.666666667f;
    const int32_t cutoff_i = 0x3f2aaaab;
#endif // LOG_VARIANT
    if ((a > 0.0f) && (a <=  0x1.fffffep+127f)) { // 3.40282347e+38f
#if PORTABLE
        m = frexpf (a, &e);
        if (m < cutoff_f) {
            m = m + m;
            e = e - 1;
        }
        i = (float)e;
#else // PORTABLE
        i = 0.0f;
        /* fix up subnormal inputs */
        if (a < 0x1.0p-126f){ // 1.175494351e-38
            a = a * 0x1.0p+23f; // 8388608.0
            i = -23.0f;
        }
        e = (float_as_int (a) - cutoff_i) & 0xff800000;
        m = int_as_float (float_as_int (a) - e);
        i = fmaf ((float)e, 0x1.0p-23f, i); // 1.19209290e-7
#endif // PORTABLE
        f = m - 1.0f;
        s = f * f;
#if LOG_VARIANT == 1
        /* Compute log1p(f) for f in [sqrt(0.5)-1, sqrt(2.0)-1] */
        r =             -0x1.384000p-4f;  // -7.62329102e-2
        t =              0x1.084000p-3f;  //  1.29028320e-1
        r = fmaf (r, s, -0x1.0f218cp-3f); // -1.32388204e-1
        t = fmaf (t, s,  0x1.226b04p-3f); //  1.41805679e-1
        r = fmaf (r, s, -0x1.5427a4p-3f); // -1.66091233e-1
        t = fmaf (t, s,  0x1.99a35ap-3f); //  2.00018600e-1
        r = fmaf (r, s, -0x1.000416p-2f); // -2.50015587e-1
        r = fmaf (t, f, r);
        r = fmaf (r, f,  0x1.55555cp-2f); //  3.33333433e-1
        r = fmaf (r, f, -0x1.fffffap-2f); // -4.99999911e-1
#elif LOG_VARIANT == 2
        /* compute log1p(f), f in [-0.25, 0.5] */ 
        r =             -0x1.738000p-5f;  // -4.53491211e-2
        t =              0x1.b02000p-4f;  //  1.05499268e-1
        r = fmaf (r, s, -0x1.0ef3e4p-3f); // -1.32301122e-1
        t = fmaf (t, s,  0x1.28c48ap-3f); //  1.44906119e-1
        r = fmaf (r, s, -0x1.54d148p-3f); // -1.66414797e-1
        t = fmaf (t, s,  0x1.995f4ap-3f); //  1.99888781e-1
        r = fmaf (r, s, -0x1.000084p-2f); // -2.50001967e-1
        r = fmaf (t, f, r);
        r = fmaf (r, f,  0x1.5555d0p-2f); //  3.33335161e-1
        r = fmaf (r, f, -0x1.000000p-1f); // -5.00000000e-1
#elif LOG_VARIANT == 3
        /* Compute log1p(f) for f in [-1/3, 1/3] */
        r =             -0x1.0ae000p-3f;  // -0.130310059
        t =              0x1.208000p-3f;  //  0.140869141
        r = fmaf (r, s, -0x1.f1988ap-4f); // -0.121483363
        t = fmaf (t, s,  0x1.1e5740p-3f); //  0.139814854
        r = fmaf (r, s, -0x1.55b36ep-3f); // -0.166846141
        t = fmaf (t, s,  0x1.99d8b2p-3f); //  0.200120345
        r = fmaf (r, s, -0x1.fffe02p-3f); // -0.249996200
        r = fmaf (t, f, r);
        r = fmaf (r, f,  0x1.5554fap-2f); //  0.333331972
        r = fmaf (r, f, -0x1.000000p-1f); // -0.500000000
#endif // LOG_VARIANT
        r = fmaf (r, s, f);
        r = fmaf (i, 0x1.62e430p-01f, r); //  6.93147182e-1  // log(2)
    } else {
        r = a + a;  // silence NaNs if necessary
        if (a  < 0.0f) r = 0.0f/0.0f; // QNaN INDEFINITE
        if (a == 0.0f) r = -INFINITY; // -INF
    }
    return r;
}
```